# Add new columns and rows

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, addition

I have PySpark dataframe:

```
cust |  prob
-------------------
A    |  0.1
B    |  0.7
C    |  0.4
```

I would like to add another column `amount` and add rows to each customer. My expected result would be:

```
cust |  prob  |  amount
------------------------
A    |  0.1   |  1000
A    |  0.1   |  2000
A    |  0.1   |  3000
A    |  0.1   |  4000
A    |  0.1   |  5000
B    |  0.7   |  1000
B    |  0.7   |  2000
B    |  0.7   |  3000
B    |  0.7   |  4000
B    |  0.7   |  5000
C    |  0.4   |  1000
C    |  0.4   |  2000
C    |  0.4   |  3000
C    |  0.4   |  4000
C    |  0.4   |  5000
```

I need help in making this new column and rows. My real data consist of many columns, so it should duplicate whatever the original column in the dataset.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add an exploded array:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df2 = df.withColumn(
    'amount',
    F.explode(
        F.array(*[F.lit(i) for i in [1000, 2000, 3000, 4000, 5000]])
    )
)
```

Or an exploded sequence:

```
df2 = df.withColumn(
    'amount',
    F.explode(
        F.sequence(F.lit(1000), F.lit(5000), F.lit(1000))
    )
)
```